# How to write this code in php? Telegram webapp bot documentation

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I've got this instrunctions from Telegram documenation
[image]

but how to write it in PHP?

I tried this one:

```
if (pack("H*",hash_hmac('sha256',$string, $secret_key)) == $info['hash']) {
```

but unsuccesfully.. any ideas how to apply this code in php?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out..

```
secret_key = HMAC_SHA256(<bot_token>, "WebAppData")
```

php equal is:

```
$secret_key = hash_hmac('sha256',$bot_token, 'WebAppData', true);
```

and

```
hex(HMAC_SHA256(data_check_string, secret_key))
```

it is just:

```
hash_hmac('sha256',$dataCheckString, $secret_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this accurately reflect your intent?

```
if(hach_hmac("sha256", $data_check_string, $secret_key) === $info['hash']){
  // data is from Telegram
}
```

If the third parameter of the hash_hmac function is not provided or is set to false, it will return a lowercase hexadecimal value. More information can be found at https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.hash-hmac.php